# pre select a value in the mat-autocomplete options list

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-table

i have 2 components, addUser and editUser. The form field values for editUser component is coming from addUser. i have used mat-autocomplete to display the value in the form. the value is displayed on the form but is not checked in the options dropdown list. How to check the value in list on page load since i have already have it ready

in HTML

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="user">
    <mat-label>{{constants.role}}</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName="roleIds" [matAutocomplete]="autoRoles">
    <mat-autocomplete #autoRoles="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let role of filteredRole | async" [value]="role.roleName">    {{role.roleName}}</mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
```

in TS

```
 @ViewChild('autoRoles') roleAutoComplete!: MatAutocomplete;

this.addUserForm.controls['roleIds'].setValue(someUser.roles[0].roleName);


getFilteredList() {
  this.filteredRole = this.addUserForm.controls['roleIds'].valueChanges.pipe(
   startWith(),
   map(value => {
    const role = typeof value === 'string' ? value : value?.roleName;
    return role ? this._filterRole(role, this.roleList): this.roleList.slice();
   })
  );
 this.addUserForm.controls['roleIds'].valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
  if(value===''){
    this.roleAutoComplete.options.forEach((item: any) => {
      item.deselect();
    });
    this.addUserForm.controls['roleIds'].setValue(null);
   }
  })
}
```

How to setActive item so that item wll be checked on load , and where should i place it?

Comment: what do you mean by checked? after selection you want one single item with correct symbol?

Comment: in options dropdown, when you select an option the value will be displayed in blue along with a check mark against the value selected. this is not happening when i bind the form value coming from other component

Comment: How to value come from component add to edit? using Input Decorators? after coming value you need to write logic of `valueChange` for controls.

Comment: yes, valuechanges is done. but how to add the check mark in the dropdown list